# characterization for symmetric function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Let $f:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb C$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^d$ ($d \in \mathbb N$).

Let $x= (x_1,...,x_x) \in \mathbb R^d, |x|= \sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_d^2}.$

> Question: Can we say $f(x) = \Phi(|x|)$ for some function $\Phi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$? What about converse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think of $$f(x_1, \dots, x_d)=x_1^2+ x_2^2 + \dots +x_{n-1}^2+2x_n^2?$$

Knowing that $$f(1,0, \dots, 0) = 1 \text{ and } f(0, \dots, 0,1) = 2$$

The converse is true as $$f(x) = \Phi(|x|) = \Phi(|-x|) = f(-x)$$

Comment: thanks.  I  understood for $d>1$ from your answer. what about $d=1$?

Comment: It is true for $d=1$, let $\Phi:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be defined by $\Phi(x)=f(x)$. Then, for $x<0$, $\Phi(|x|)=\Phi(-x)=f(-x)=f(x)$

Comment: @abcd This is true for $d=1$. Your turn to prove it.